# Flex AdvancedDatagrid groupIconFunction on Mac to display Image as Retina (scaled down)

Tags: macos, flexbox, air

I'm using an AdvancedDataGrid that uses a groupIconFunction to return the icon near the arrow (top level tree) as a custom Image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                     lockedColumnCount="4"
                     groupIconFunction="getGroupIcon">
```

in the <fx:Script>:

```
    [Embed(source="/images/customTreeNodeImg.png")]
    [Bindable] public var nodeImg:Class;
    
    protected function getGroupIcon(item:Object, depth:int):Class {
        return nodeImg;
    }
```

The issue here is that the Image is blurry. I sense I need to scale the Class down, or some other way I can make the Image clear?
If I double the size of customTreeNodeImg.png, the image size is doubled, and still blurry. The default folder is clear.

How would I go about making my custom Image of the icon display clearly in Retina?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Import the original svg into Illustrator and scale it to the size needed in Illustrator, then Export to swf.

Then import into Flex:

```
    Embed(source="/images/customTreeNodeImg.swf")] // <--- swf / vector
    [Bindable] public var nodeImg:Class;
```